# Jacobian of Fourier Transformation

Tags: fourier-series, transformation, coordinate-systems

I am trying to calculate the Jacobian determinate of the Fourier transform which I stumbled upon when studying the Path Integral in Quantum Field Theory. I know the answer should be $1$ but I don't know how to show it. The transform is
\begin{equation} 
x _n = \sum _k \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ N} }e ^{ - i 2 \pi k n/N } \tilde{x} _k 
\end{equation} 
I know that the Jacobian matrix is given by 
\begin{equation} 
J _{ n,k} = \frac{ dx _n }{ d\tilde{x} _k } =  \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ N}} e ^{ - i 2 \pi k n/N}
\end{equation} 
and the determinate is then 
\begin{equation} 
\det J = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ N}}\epsilon _{ k _1 k _2 ... } e ^{ - i 2 \pi k _1 1/N } e ^{ - i 2 \pi k _1 2 /N} ... 
\end{equation} 
but I'm not sure how to show this is equal to one. I found a link [online](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/classes/2008f.homeworks/osc.pdf%E2%80%8E) which says to calulate the determinate you should perform the Fourier Transform twice but I wasn't able to figure out the steps.

Comment: There might be another idea. Fourier transfrom is an isometry (up to a constant factor depending on the conventions used in the definition of FT), therefore it's sort of orthogonal transform, and hence its determinant is $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $Q$ be an orthonormal matrix. By definition, orthonormal matrices are the matrices which satisfy the following conditions:

($i$) $Q^{-1}=Q^T$. From here it follows that $QQ^T=QQ^{-1}=I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix, a square matrix with $1$s at the diagonal and else $0$.

($ii$) All rows and columns of an orthonormal matrix satisfy the inner product rule $<q_i,q_j>=0$ and $<q_i,q_i>=1$.

A matrix is called orthogonal (but not necessarily orthonomal) when $<q_i,q_j>=0$ holds. This means the angle beween two pairs, $i$ and $j$ of vectors from $Q$ with $i\neq j$ is $90$ degrees. This follows simply from $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{<u_i,u_j>}{||u_i||||u_j||}$$ here $||u_i||=<u_i,u_i>$ is the inner product in Euclidean space ($L^2$ norm).

Absolute value of the determinant of every orthonormal matrix is always $1$. This can be proven at least in two different ways:

$1$ **st way**: $$1=\det(I)=\det(QQ^T)=\det(Q)\det(Q^T)=(\det(Q))^2$$
The third equality is a result of the determinant of two square matrices [here the 4th property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant).

$2$ **nd way**:

($i$) For every orthonormal matrix, $Q$, all singular values $\sigma_i$ of this matrix are equal to $1$

($ii$) The determinant of any real matrix is given by $|\det(A)|=\prod_i \sigma_i^2$

from ($i$) and ($ii$) we conclude that $|\det(A)|=(\prod_i 1)^2\Longrightarrow |\det(A)|=1$.

The proof of ($i$):

For every real matrix $Q$ we have the singular value decomposition given by $Q=U\Sigma V^T$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthonormal matrices. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). One can select $U=Q$ and $V=I$. From here we get $\Sigma=I$. Since $\Sigma$ is uniquely determined for singular value decomposition, the proof is complete. Note that $U$ and $V$ are not unique.

The proof of ($ii$):

For this proof one can see either [this, proposition C.3.7](http://www.theanalysisofdata.com/probability/C_3.html) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues) and the following answers.

To show that $J_{n,k}$ forms an orthonormal basis is easy to justify by the given properties of orthonormal matrices. Therefore, we can eventually conclude that $|\det J|=1$.