# How does my characteristic equation change if I "know" beforehand that one of the eigenvalues are $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I am given a $3 \times 3$ matrix, and I need to compute its eigenvalues. How would I be able to tell, by inspection, if the matrix has at least one eigenvalue $= 0$?

Then suppose I know that one of eigenvalues are in fact zero. Are there any shortcuts/simplifications that will allow me to compute the other eigenvalues without having to go through the same tedious calculations for the eigenvalues (and eigenvectors) of a $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Comment: This may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755780/assume-that-the-square-matrix-a-has-an-eigenvalue-of-0-is-a-invertible-why-or

Answer (score 1):

A matrix has $0$ as an eigenvalue if and only if it has nonempty kernel. So if you can inspect a nonzero vector whose image is the $0$ vector, you're set.

Alternatively, a matrix has $0$ as an eigenvalue if and only if its determinant is $0$. If you have been doing this for a little bit, you might be able to compute determinants quickly in your head.

In this case, there really can't be a method to find the other two eigenvalues much shorter than simply calculating the characteristic polynomial. You know that you'll get a quadratic and you can always use the quadratic formula to immediately give the eigenvalues.