# In the following equation $Av = \lambda v$ $v$ cannot be $\vec{0}$

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fake-proofs

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755780/assume-that-the-square-matrix-a-has-an-eigenvalue-of-0-is-a-invertible-why-or) and answers to such question people say that $v$ **cannot** be $\vec{0}$, but this not correct in my opinion. We assume it is different from $\vec{0}$ because otherwise $Av = \lambda v$  would be trivially true, right?

So, instead of saying "but this is a contradiction because $v$ cannot be $\vec{0}$" we should say "but this is a contradiction because, by assumption, $v \neq \vec{0}$", right?

I just wanted to clarify this point.

Comment: If you assume $v$ is an eigenvector and conclude that $v=0$ then you have derived a contradiction and can conclude that $v$ is not an eigenvector.

Comment: You could separately assume $v$ is nonzero, or you could assume $v$ is an eigenvector, it is the same.

Comment: To add to Ian’s point: by definition, eigenvectors are non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

As it states already in the question, thats the contradiction...

(sorry cant comment as of yet)