# prove the following results for the eigenvalues of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove the following results for the eigenvalues of an $n \times  n$ matrix $A$:

(a) $0$ is an eigenvalue for $A$ if and only if $A$ is not invertible.

(b) $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755780/is-a-matrix-a-with-an-eigenvalue-of-0-invertible , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123923/a-matrix-and-its-transpose-have-the-same-set-of-eigenvalues

Comment: $\det (0 \cdot I -A) = 0$ **iff** $A$ is singular, and $\det (sI-A) = \det (sI-A)^T$.

Comment: (b) See [link] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123923/a-matrix-and-its-transpose-have-the-same-set-of-eigenvalues)

Answer (score 1):

(a) Suppose $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Then $Av=0v$ for some
nonzero vector $v$. What does that mean?

(b) Look at the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$ and the
characteristic polynomial of its transpose. What can you say about
them?