# Is it true that the determinant of symmetric positive definite matrix is the product of the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I was working with a symmetric positive definite matrix when I encountered upon the following "identity"

Let A be symmetric pd

$\det(A)$

$= \det(Q\Lambda Q^{-1})$ (all symmetric matrices diag'able)

$ = \det(Q)\det(\Lambda)\det(Q^{-1})$ (product of symmetric matrices)

$ = \det(Q) \det(\Lambda) \dfrac{1}{\det{Q}}$ (determinant of inverse, property of orthogonal matrices)

$ = \det(\Lambda)$ (determinant of diagonal matrix)

$ = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$

I looked for sometimes for a verification of this claim, but I did not come up with anything. Can anyone check that the claim is indeed correct or false?

Comment: The claim is correct and $A$ don't have to be positive definite (Only need to be symmetric).

Comment: The determinant of any square matrix is the product of its eigenvalues.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Hi can you provide a reference, thanks

Comment: @illegal immigrant: practically any linear algebra text - up to sign the constant term of the characteristic polynomial is the product of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Just to be sure, by eigenvalue I need some $\lambda$ so that $Av = \lambda v$ for some nonzero $v$. If eigenvalues are defined as roots of the characteristic polynomials, then the statement is true for all $A$, as linked in the answer.

Comment: Simply write the matrix in a basis of its eigenvectors. Then it is obvious that the determinant is the product of its eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the claim is indeed true. The determinant of a matrix is equal to the product of its eigenvalues. 
Check this link [determinant is equal to the product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues)

Comment: Wow so it is for every matrix. I don't know why I am shocked because I probably derived this a thousand times before but just seeing it used in a completely different context (convex optimization) has led me to believe it is some work of ingenuity of the optimization field not linear algebra