# How to tackle this polynomial given as a determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinant

Let $$p (x) = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & x & x & \dots & x & x \\
x & 1 & x & \dots & x & x \\
x & x & 1 & \dots & x & x \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
x & x & x & \dots & 1 & x \\
x & x & x & \dots & x & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} .$$

How to find the (multiple) zeroes, the degree of the polynomial and the initial coefficient, all depending on the natural number $b$?

Comment: What $b$?There is no $b$ in your question.

Answer (score 6):

Add all columns (from second one) to the first one and then substract first row from all the rest:

$$\begin{vmatrix}1+(n-1)x&x&x&\ldots&x\\0&1-x&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&1-x&\ldots&0\\..&..&..&..&..\\0&0&0&\ldots&1-x\end{vmatrix}=\left(1+(n-1)x\right)(1-x)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You can determine the characteristic polynomial of the corresponding matrix. Note that the matrix is symmetric and therefore diagonalizable. Now $-x + 1$ is an eigenvalue with a geometric multiplicity of at least $n - 1$ and the sum of all eigenvalues [according to their algebraic multiplicity] is equal to the trace of the matrix.

Once you've calculated the characteristic polynomial you can determine $p(x)$ by plugging in $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: n-1  zeros are only 1 ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I do not understand, which numbers are zeros ?

Comment: You first need to calculate the characteristic polynomial, then you will be able to calculate the zeroes of $p$.

Comment: Actually, you don't really *need* to exhibit the characteristic polynomial, as the determinant is simply the product of eigenvalues (but both ways to view this are equivalent, of course). @Algebra2015 see also this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues

Comment: So, how to at the end write down the polynom, depending on the natural number n ?