# On the integral of matrix functions

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

Why does the following integral hold?
$$\large \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{( \det 2 \pi A)^{1/2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^T \cdot A^{-1}\cdot x}dx =1 $$
where $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ positive definite symmetric matrix.

And if we want to generalize the formula to any dimensions, for example
$$\large \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f(A)} e^{-{A_{ijkl}} X_i X_j X_k X_l}dX =1 $$
How can we find such a function $f$?

Comment: Look at the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_and_functional_generalization)

Comment: Thanks. But I still have no idea how to solve the second part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

This result possesses a probabilistic interpretation: $f(x)=\frac{1}{(2 \pi \det A)^{1/2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^T \cdot A^{-1}\cdot x}$ is the probability density function (pdf) of a certain multivariate normal (or gaussian) distribution ; it is thus "normal" that its integral is equal to 1, $A$ being interpreted as the **variance matrix** of this distribution. See for example (http://www.real-statistics.com/multivariate-statistics/multivariate-normal-distribution/multivariate-normal-distribution-basic-concepts/).

If $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, the case of independance of corresponding random variables $X_k$ nicely matches the case where $A=diag(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)$ ( $\sigma_k$ being the variance of $X_k$), which itself corresponds to the case where the triple integral splits into 3 separable integrals.

Answer (score 0):

Your first formula is wrong. The correct version is:
$$ \int \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{1}{2} x^T \cdot A^{-1} x} \operatorname{d}^3 x = (2\pi)^{3/2} \sqrt{\operatorname{det}(A)}.$$

If $A$ is positive definite and symmetric, then you can diagonalize it into the form:
$$A = V^T \Lambda V,$$
where $V$ is the normalized matrix of $A$'s eigenvectors (an othogonal matrix) and $\Lambda$ is the matrix of the eigenvalues. Do a change of variables on the integral $x' = V x$, and the answer falls right out. The generalized $N$-dimensional version is:
$$ \int \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{1}{2} x^T \cdot A^{-1} x} \operatorname{d}^N x = (2\pi)^{N/2} \sqrt{\operatorname{det}(A)}.$$

Edit to add: the generalized integral provided is not of the same form as the simple 3-d case. The one with $A$ a rank 4 tensor and 4 factors of the $x$ vector in the exponent is, as far as I now, an unsolved problem, especially when there is also a term in the exponent with a different rank 2 $A$ and 2 factors the $x$ vector in it.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide some reference on this topic? Especially when $A$ is a symmetric tensor.

Comment: The proofs involved are very short -- 1 or 2 lines each. Any introductory text on quantum mechanics, for example R. Shankar's **Principles of Quantum Mechanics**, should suffice. Or look in your linear algebra text for eigenvectors and eigenvalues, and it should have proofs on the orthogonality of eigenvectors. Mathworld has a nice bit on [orthogonal matrices](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalMatrix.html). Axler's **Linear Algebra Done Right** is also good for fundamentals (basis sets, etc).

Comment: I mean on the second part of my question.

Comment: You mean the one where $A$ is a rank 4 tensor? For that one I have no help to give and would, honestly, be very interested in an answer, myself. If that was a mistake, though, and you meant something like what I typed (i.e. an $N$-dimensional Gaussian integral), then I outlined the proof. After you change variables, the multi-integral factors into $N$ single integrals. You then only need to know that the [determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues).

Comment: Thanks. I have understand your answer. I want to know the rank 4 case.

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but you could try something like the following:
$$\int \operatorname{e}^{-A_{ijkl} x_i x_j x_k x_l} \operatorname{d}^N x = \int \delta^N(x-y) \operatorname{e}^{-A_{ijkl} x_i x_j y_k y_l} \operatorname{d}^N x \operatorname{d}^N y$$,
and go from there, but I don't know if it would pan out. ($\delta^n(x)$ is an $N$-dimensional [delta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html)).