# Relation of eigenvalues and invertibilty of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Proof that if a matrix has no eigenvalues, it'll not be invertible:

$$
\det(A-\lambda I) = 0 \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1}-\lambda & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}-\lambda & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \cdots & a_{n,n}-\lambda
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If all $\lambda=0$, we would get that our $\det(A) = 0$, hence, it would not be invertible.

Is this proof correct?!

Comment: Saying that $A$ has no eigenvalues is different from saying that $A$ has zero as its only eigenvalue

Comment: $A$ is invertible **iff** $\det A \neq 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Since we get $\det A = 0$ I've proved it?!

Comment: Sure, modulo some correct wording. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ **iff** $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$. Hence $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ **iff** $\det A = 0$ **iff** $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues. For a simple proof see [Show that the determinant of $A$ is equal to the product of its eigenvalues.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues).

So, if **one** (not all) eigenvalue is zero the determinant is zero and the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If det (A)=0, then A has the eigenvalue 0