# True or False Linear Transformation Eigenvalues Question

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$ and let $T :V \to V$ be a linear transformation. Let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis for $V$. For each of the following assertions, state whether it is true or not. If the assertion is true, briefly justify why this is so; otherwise, provide a counter-example.
>
> (a) If $T$ is diagonalisable then each of its eigenvalues has algebraic multiplicity equal to $1$.
>
> (b) If none of the eigenvalues of $T$ are zero then the determinant of $A$ is not zero.
>
> (c) If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors for $T$ associated to eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively, then $v_1 + v_2$ is an eigenvector for $T$ with associated eigenvalue $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$.

For (a) I gave a counterexample and said it was false. Is this the correct answer?

For (b) I think it is correct since the determinant of characteristic polynomial of $A$ can only be zero if there is no eigenvalue. Is this correct? If so is there a theorem that proves that?

For (c) I said it is false since eigenvalues added together does not form a new eigenvalue for $T$, is this correct?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Each of your truth values is correct.  For $(b)$, there is a theorem which says that the [determinant is the product of the eigenvalues](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues).  So $\det(A) = 0 \iff$ at least one of the eigenvalues is $0$.  For $(c)$, remember that you're supposed to come up with a counterexample.  There are simple ones.

Answer (score 1):

Assertion (a) is false, as you say.  $T$ the identity map is a counterexample.  Assertion (b) is true, since the determinant of $T$ is the product of its eigenvalues (with multiplicity).  Assertion (c) is false, as we can see when $T$ is scalar multiplication by 2.  Every eigenvalue is 2; 4 is not an eigenvalue.