# Why does the characteristic polynomial have only factors from the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In all the proofs of the determinant being the product of the eigenvalues I can find, including the one listed below, we start with the assumption that if $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,...,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues for $A$ then $\text{det}(A-\lambda I)=(-1)^n\prod_{i=1}^n(\lambda_i-\lambda)$. I understand that the $\lambda_i$ are roots of the char polynomial and thus each $(\lambda-\lambda_i)$ will be a factor, but how do we know there are no other factors? Specifically, how do we know there are no other factors which are polynomials with no roots?

[Show that the determinant of $A$ is equal to the product of its eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your matrix $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and that $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are all the eigenvalues, eventually with repetitions (for instance, if $A=\operatorname{Id}$, then each $\lambda_k$ is equal to $1$). If that is so, then $\deg\det(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})=n$ and therefore there is no room for other factors. Besides, this proof assumes that we are working in an algebraically clased field, such as $\mathbb C$, and in such a field there are no non-constant polynomials without roots.