# Rank of a matrix and cross product between eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, cross-product

I have two questions about linear algebra.
I was doing a exercise that says:
Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix $3 \times 3$ and $\det A = 6  $. Suppose that $u =(4,8,-1)$ and $v=(1,0,4)$ are eigenvectors of $A$ and $1$ and $2$ the eigenvalues associated respectively.

My first conclusion about $\det A=6\neq 0$ is the matrix $A$ is full rank so its rows are L.I (Linear independent), I was trying to figure out a way to link this result with the number of eigenvalues of matrix $A$, because the first question says:

1) The eigenvalues of $A$ are only $1$ and $2$?

If my first conclusion is wrong(i'm not sure), how to use the information from the statement to conclude that is false.

2) The cross product $u \times v$ is necessarily a eigenvector ?

For this one, I've calculated the cross product that result $(32, -17, -8)$, but I don't how to follow from this and prove that.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Also remember that the determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues

Comment: I didn't know it! But i've read a little in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues

So the first question is answered by this fact!

Comment: Yes, since the matrix is of full rank, there is only one possibility for the last eigenvalue. Of course the eigenvectors need not be completely orthogonal unless the matrix is symmetric

Comment: if matrix A wasn't full rank, is there other possibility?

Comment: Well it might mean a zero eigenvalue or a repeated one

Comment: You could try going back to basics for part b: multiply $u\times v$ by $A$ and see what you get.

Comment: On the other hand, it’s a basic fact about real symmetric matrices that eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal.

Comment: I can't multiply $u \times v$ by $A$ because I don't know $A$, I just know that is symmetric. Is a orthogonal vector in relation the eigenvectors a eigenvector too

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, it is diagonalizable and there is an orthogonal basis of $\Bbb R^3$ which consists of eigenvalues of $A$. So, automatically you have that $(4,8,1)\times(1,0,-4)$ is an eigenvector of $A$. And the corresponding eigenvalue has to be $3$, since the product of the eigenvalues has to be $\det A$, which is $6$.