# Where did the $(-1)^n$ in $\det(A - \lambda I)$ come from?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In [Show that the determinant of $A$ is equal to the product of its eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues), the accepted answer states that

$$
\det(A_{n \times n} - \lambda I_{n \times n}) = (-1)^n \prod_{i=1}^n (\lambda - \lambda_i)
$$

and states that "$(-1)^n$ can be found by expanding the determinant along the diagonal."

What does "expanding the determinant along the diagonal" mean? Is there another way to see where the $(-1)^n $ came from?

Comment: In other words: the $(-1)^n$ is the coefficient of $\lambda^n$ in the expanded polynomial. Among the products in the Leibniz expansion of the determinant, the product along the main diagonal is the only one that results in a $\lambda^n$ when expanded.

Comment: The $(-1)^n$ term, in my opinion, shouldn't be there; the characteristic polynomial should be defined as $\det(\lambda I - A)$ to fix this, so that it's always monic.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Isn't it more traditional to use $\det(A - \lambda I)$ when finding the characteristic polynomial and eigenvalues? I've never seen $\det(\lambda I - A)$ in my studies, although it seems you get the same eigenvalues, but just $\det(-A) = -\det(A)$ when you set $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: @David: yes, but it’s a bad tradition. The correct statement is that $\det(-A) = (-1)^n \det(A)$ which incidentally is one way to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What does 'expanding the determinant along the diagonal' mean?"

$$A_{n \times n} - \lambda I_{n \times n} =
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11} - \lambda & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} - \lambda & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn} - \lambda
\end{pmatrix}$$

The "leading term" from Laplace expansion of $\det(A_{n \times n} - \lambda I_{n \times n})$ is the product of the main diagonal entries,
$$\det(A_{n \times n} - \lambda I_{n \times n}) = (a_{11} - \lambda)\cdots (a_{nn} - \lambda) + \cdots.$$
For instance, if the matrix were diagonal, then $\cdots$ would be $0$ and this would be the entirety of the determinant. In general, this is the only term that will contribute $\lambda^n$; all the rest will have at most $n-1$ copies of $\lambda$. Hence
$$\det(A_{n \times n} - \lambda I_{n \times n}) = (-\lambda)^n + \cdots = (-1)^n \lambda^n + \cdots.$$

You can also just do the $n=1$ case, which makes it very clear.