# On the $\log \det$ of identity matrix plus a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: derivatives, determinant, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices, scalar-fields

I am trying to learn some matrix differentiation, and came across example of calculating the derivative of $$f(X)=\log\det(X)$$ where the $X$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.
I came to the underlined step, but I couldn't make out how this step is derived. What's the theory or theorems underlying this step? I tried to look into the determinant formulas to work it out, but sadly, failed. So, would anyone please be kind enough to explain to me?

---

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you, updated as above...

Comment: Is that screenshot from Boyd & Vandenberghe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to use the fact that the [determinant of a matrix is given by the product of its eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues) so if $A$ is any matrix and its eigenvalues are $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ then
$$
\det A = \prod_{i=1}^n \alpha_i.
$$
Using the fact that the log of a product is the sum of the logs it follows
$$
\log \det A = \log \left ( \prod_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \right )= \sum_{i=1}^n \log(\alpha_i)
$$
The rest of the work is applying the fact that for any matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ the matrix $I+A$ has eigenvalues $1+\alpha_1,...,1+\alpha_n$. To see this let $v_i$ be the $i$th eigenvector of $A$, that is $Av_i = \alpha_iv_i$. Then
$$
(I+A)v_i = Iv_i + Av_i = 1v_i + \alpha_iv_i = (1+\alpha_i)v_i.
$$
Combining this with the identity for $\log \det$ gives for any matrix $A$ that
$$\log \det (I + A) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1 + \alpha_i).$$
The line in question is just applying this formula with $A = X^{-1/2}\Delta X X^{-1/2}$ since they assume $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $X^{-1/2}\Delta X X^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much...