# Finding determinant and rank of matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Finding rank of this matrix :
$$A_{n\times n}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a+1&a&\cdots&a\\
a&a+1&\cdots&a\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a&a&\cdots&a+1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$(a\geq 2, a\in \mathbb{N})$
I'm trying to prove $det(A) \ne 0$ so that $rank(A)=n$ but I don't know how to prove it quickly. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio sr, i forgot to write conditions of a

Comment: The sum of each row is same, so 'the sum' could be took out. Then you will find the determinant by simple substraction by rows.

Comment: @CunyiNan still not get it, can u explain it ?

Comment: **Note**: An especially efficient method to determine the value of a determinant of order $n$ can be obtained if we transform it in the same way we do in order to determine the rank of a matrix, i.e., all the elements under the diagonal $a_{11}, a_{22}, \ldots a_{nn}$ are equal to zero. Then the value of the determinant is the product of the diagonal elements of the transformed determinant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach. One has $$A = I_n + B$$

where $I_n$ is the identity matrix, and $B$ is the matrix whose all coefficients are equal to $a$. Since all the rows of $B$ are equal and $a \neq 0$, then $B$ has rank $1$, so the eigenvalues of $B$ are $0$ (with multiplicity $n-1$) and $\mathrm{Tr}(B)=na$ (with multiplicity $1$).

So the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ (with multiplicity $n-1$) and $na+1$ (with multiplicity $1$). In particular,
$$\det(A)=1^{n-1} \times (na+1)^1 = na+1, \quad \text{i.e.} \quad \boxed{\det(A)=na+1}$$

Since $\det(A) \neq 0$, you get that the rank of $A$ is equal to $n$.

Comment: I don't understand how you find det(A) by using eigenvalues, kinda hard to understand, maybe I don't understand the property of eigenvalue you use for proving.

Comment: The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues (when you repeat them accordingly with their multiplicities). See for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues).

Comment: Oh, then why 0 with multiplicity n-1, how can u find it ?

Comment: Since $B$ has rank $1$, then $\mathrm{Ker}(B)$ has dimension $n-1$, so $0$ is eigenvalue of $B$ of multiplicity at least $n-1$ (and obviously not $n$, since $\mathrm{Tr}(B)\neq 0$).

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for new knowledge, idk the determiant can be found by using eigenvalues.

Comment: @user307596 You are welcome !